# Underline a single character in a string using CSS

Tags: css

I want to have hotkeys using `accesskey`.

Let's say I have this (it's AnguarJs but that doesn't matter):

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default"  
   ng-click="CancelCampaignEdit();" accesskey='n'  
   style="margin-right:10%">Cancel</button>
```

As you can see, I want to assign the hotkey `n` to this button. How could I underline the `n` in `Cancel` using CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a span tag with `text-decoration:underline` if you want add extra styling. Otherwise use  tag

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default"  
   ng-click="CancelCampaignEdit();" accesskey='n'  
   style="margin-right:10%">Ca<u>n</u>cel</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default"  
   ng-click="CancelCampaignEdit();" accesskey='n'  
        style="margin-right:10%">Ca<span style="text-decoration: underline;">n</span>cel</button>
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. I guess I will declare a `hotkey` class to my CSS and apply that to the span.

Comment: HTML5 brought back <u> tag which was depreciated  in 4. When I saw your comment that it isn't a valid tag, I have added it to my answer to suggest alternate ways and a link to http://www.html-5.com/tags/u-tag/#whats-new

Comment: Wow!! I didn't know it was back - then that is the obvious answer.

Comment: The other guy deleted his answer (which I woudl have awarded), so you get it. You are correct <u> is back http://html5doctor.com/u-element/